# No output from SQL Server 2005 T-SQL and PDO when using SET

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pdo

I am connecting to a SQL Server 2005 database using PDO and don't get output when running certain types of queries using PHP, but I do when running the queries directly in SQL Server Management Studio.

When I run this:

```
$conn = new PDO(...);

$statement = $conn->prepare("
    DECLARE @testvar VARCHAR(10)
    SELECT 'hello world'
");

$result = $statement->execute();

echo $result ? "Success" : "Failure";
echo "<br>";

print_r($conn->errorInfo());
echo "<br>";

die(print_r($statement->fetchAll()));
```

I get output.

```
Success
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 0 [2] => (null) [0] (severity 0) [] [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [] => hello world ) ) 1
```

However, if I change the query to set `@testvar` to something, either inline:

```
DECLARE @testvar VARCHAR(10) = 'test'
SELECT 'hello world'
```

Or by using SET:

```
DECLARE @testvar VARCHAR(10)
SET @testvar = 'test'
SELECT 'hello world'
```

I no longer get `"hello world"` when running `$statement->fetchAll()`, and there does not seem to be an error:

```
Success
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 0 [2] => (null) [0] (severity 0) [] [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
Array ( ) 1
```

When I try all three of the queries above directly in SQL Server Management Studio, all three of them work and return `"hello world"` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Using `SET` (either inline with the `DECLARE` or as an explicit `SET`) causes the results to now have more than one rowset in PDO terms. The `"hello world"` string I'm looking for is not in the first rowset.

Instead of this:

```
die(print_r($statement->fetchAll()));
```

Iterate through all the rowsets:

```
do {
    print_r($statement->fetchAll());
    echo "<br>";
}
while ($statement->nextRowset());
```

And now the result looks like this:

```
Array ( ) // rowset 1
Array ( [0] => Array ( [] => hello world ) )  // rowset 2
```

Comment: It looks like a good answer but in fact, in my case, nextRowset() is always returning false. there is several DECLARE and with these DECLARE, it returns nothing but without the DECLAREs, it returns results.